# Implementing difficult model relations in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

Can't implement provided scheme in mongoid without `has_ through`:

User has many posts and belongs to many projects, and, depending on the participation in some projects, belongs to some sections, can be admin in project

Section has many projects, users and posts

Project has many posts and users, belongs to many sections, some users are admins here(`belong` relation?)

Post belongs to one user, project and many sections

How?

Use polymorphic associations for everything?

My code: http://pastebin.com/sFzs1FD8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by myself:)

```
# Models:
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
  has_many :posts, inverse_of: :author
end

class Project
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :posts, inverse_of: :project
end

class Post
  belongs_to :project, inverse_of: :posts
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
end
```